# Silverlight 2 dynamic data binding Converter

Tags: silverlight, xaml, dynamic, binding, converters

In Silverlight 2....

I have a RadioButton in my xaml code as follows:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Gender" Content="Male" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Gender, ConverterParameter=1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource RadioStringConverter}}" Width="49" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

This works great.  My issue is in trying to duplicate this functionallity dynamically.

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() {GroupName = "Gender", Content = "Male" ,Width = (double)49,HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left};
```

this works but when I try to put the converter in, it breaks.  What is the proper way to do this?  Any good working examples?

Here is what I tried....

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() {GroupName = "Gender", Content = "Male" ,Width = (double)49,HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left};

RadioStringConverter rsc = new RadioStringConverter();

Binding binding = new Binding(layout.FieldName) { Source = mainLayout.DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,ConverterParameter = 1,Converter = rsc};  // to emulate the "{StaticResource RadioStringConverter}"};

rb.SetBinding(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);

sp.Children.Add(rb);
```

Although this compiles fine, it does not run correctly.
1) How do I reference the static resource dynamically?
2) How do I add this static resource to the XAML dynamically?  Right now I have this reference hard coded.

Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found....
Basically I had to create an instance of the converter class and pass it's interface to the converter as such:

```
Binding binding = new Binding(layout.FieldName) { Source = mainLayout.DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,ConverterParameter = 1,Converter = (rsc as IValueConverter)};
```

Glad it turned out simple and doable :)

Answer (score 0):

Although it IS possible, as you have found out, are you sure you want to be creating the RadioButton dynamically?

I have been there... I have written the exact same code... but I soon realized that I was just doing it wrong.  In my case, I used an ItemsControl, and bound the values using a template... completely eliminating the need to create them by myself dynamically.

I obviously don't know the larger context, but consider if you should be doing this more declaratively using some sort of dynamic container instead.

Actually, after I discovered MVVM, I completely eliminated the need for data converters at the UI layer.  Data converters are obsolete with MVVM :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on MVVM as well as the dynamic containers?  I'd love to see some small samples on your approach to this!

Comment: So, you can find a lot of information on the web about MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)... just search for it.  It essentially makes the XAML a layer on top of everything else, and eliminates all (most of) your code-behind.  Your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and is a representation of the UI (properties for Visibility, Enabled, Data, Commands, etc).  In this case, you create a view model that has everything you want in it... a bool for selected state, the text, possibly an enum for the group, etc.  Then, a small user control that binds to the ViewModel.

Comment: @Brian Genisio It is such a big statement:Data converters are obsolete with MVVM. I got various controls binding to single object. Instead of creating various fields being some kind of representation of that object and using several PropertyChangedEvents I fire single event and let converters do their job to display it as image, text, %, and bool. Could you say your approach for such situation, without converters. Because there is a chance I am completely missing sonething.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub  Hard to say, actually... I have come up with lots of fun ways of doing things in ViewModels... I'd have to see exactly what you are doing.  But, you are correct, saying that "converters are obsolete" is hyperbole.